# How to position a Popover component based on the user's caret position?

Tags: block-editor, full-site-editing

Been working on this for a few days and about half way there, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76425306/wordpress-gutenberg-popover-how-to-position-at-the-cursor

Basically, I've been able to get the position on the Popover component working correctly, but only in the editor, not the full site editor. I'm also using the now deprecated prop `getAnchorRect` and been looking into a way to use the latest `anchor` prop.

Here's what I've got using the `getAnchorRect` prop. Like I said, works in the editor, but not the full site editor:

```js
import {
    registerFormatType,
    toggleFormat
} from '@wordpress/rich-text';
import { Fragment } from '@wordpress/element';
import { BlockControls, RichTextShortcut } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { Popover, ToolbarButton, ToolbarGroup } from '@wordpress/components';
import { displayShortcut } from '@wordpress/keycodes';
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';

const InsertMyPopup = {
    name: 'insertmypopup',
    title: __('My Popup'),
    character: 'o',
    value: '',
};

const { name, title, character } = InsertMyPopup;
const type = `my-popup/${name}`;
let anchorRange;
let anchorRect;

registerFormatType(type, {
    title,
    tagName: name,
    className: null,
    active: false,

    edit({ isActive, value, onChange, contentRef }) {
        const onToggle = () => {
            // Set up the anchorRange when the Popover is opened.
            const selection = document.defaultView.getSelection();

            anchorRange =
                selection.rangeCount > 0 ? selection.getRangeAt(0) : null;

            // Pin the Popover to the caret position.
            const boundingClientRect = anchorRange
                ? anchorRange.getBoundingClientRect()
                : null;

            anchorRect = anchorRange ? () => boundingClientRect : null;
            onChange(toggleFormat(value, { type }));
        };

        const thePopover = isActive && (
            <Popover
                placement='bottom-start'
                focusOnMount='firstElement'
                key='my-popover'
                expandOnMobile={true}
                headerTitle={__(
                    'My Popup',
                    'insert-my-popup'
                )}
                onClose={() => {
                    onChange(toggleFormat(value, { type }));
                }}
                getAnchorRect={anchorRect}
            >
                Popup
            </Popover>
        );

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <BlockControls group='other'>
                    <ToolbarGroup>
                        <ToolbarButton
                            icon='editor-customchar'
                            isPressed={isActive}
                            label={title}
                            onClick={onToggle}
                            shortcut={displayShortcut.primary(character)}
                        />
                    </ToolbarGroup>
                </BlockControls>
                <Fragment>
                    <RichTextShortcut
                        type='primary'
                        character={character}
                        onUse={onToggle}
                        contentRef={contentRef}
                    />
                </Fragment>
                {thePopover}
            </Fragment>
        );
    },
});
```

I need the positioning to work like the link in the toolbar which appears to work in both places. I've tried looking into how that's been done and as far as I can tell it's calling `window.getSelection()` (vs. `document.defaultView.getSelection()` that I'm doing). I've tried that, works in the editor, but again, doesn't work in FSE.

It's driving me crazy, any help would be much appreciated.